# Noobie in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, command

I just started doing some bash script from few days 
I am not getting any output when running this bash script in terminal
please correct me here:

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Usage:"
echo -n "Please enter t/n"
read o
echo -n "IP"
read ip
traceroute () {
  traceroute $ip
}
nmap () {
  nmap -T4 -A -v $ip
}
if [[ "$o" = "t" ]]
then
  traceroute
elif [[ "$o" = "n" ]]
then
  nmap
else
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "Please enter t/n"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You are not even getting _Usage:_?

Comment: Could you describe how you are trying to run this script, what are the access rights and what output you get when running the script?

Comment: also, I don't think you meant to write `/n` but rather `\n` (the correct symbol for newlines)

Comment: i am running it in root terminal with `bash file.bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit immediately after 'read ip' isn't necessary, as it actually doesn't do anything (so far as I can tell).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Usage:"
echo -n "Please enter t/n"
read o
echo -n "IP"
read ip
if [[ "$o" = "t" ]]
then
  traceroute $ip
elif [[ "$o" = "n" ]]
then
  nmap -T4 -A -v $ip
else
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "Please enter t/n"
  exit 1
fi
```

The above amended code works but could do with some formatting to make it look a little nicer.

Answer (score 2):

You've made an infinite loop. Choose a solution (1st one is preferred)

- don't use `traceroute` and `nmap` as function name
- use the full path of `/usr/bin/traceroute` and `/usr/bin/nmap`